# Batch update in Postgresql JDBC driver rolls back in autocommit

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, batch-updates

I am doing batch inserts using postgres 9.3-1100-jdbc41 JDBC4 driver.

According to the JDBC specification, its up
to the application to disable autocommit and to commit or
rollback the transaction.

In my case, I am not using any transaction(i.e., auto commit is true) but still the inserts are rolled back if one of the insert in the batch fails.

According to JDBC specification "If one of the commands in a batch update fails to execute properly, this method throws a 
 BatchUpdateException, and a JDBC driver may or may not continue to process the remaining commands 
 in the batch.". Here it does not says that previously executed commands will be rolled back.

Is my understanding wrong? If not why driver is behaving in this way and if yes what is the right behavior according to specification.

Comment: If you are using auto-commit all batched inserts are still done in a single transaction if I'm not mistaken. Think of it as a different way of writing a single insert that insert many rows (`insert into .. values (..),(..),(..),(..)`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what about the specification. I think It is just to avoid round trips over the network for each inserts and to apply transaction should be depending on the Application. On the db each inserts should be executed as a single unit.
As a user I may add non related inserts in a single batch to avoid round trip, which should not be rolled back if some command fails.

Comment: Well the specification says "*may or may not continue to process*" - Postgres choses to not continue.

Comment: the specification says "may or may not continue to process further commands"
I have also found this link but it is too old,
http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/m1giot8rue5tsqrp8g8cenpmg0rep3is5c@4ax.com

Comment: So what's unclear about "*may **not** continue*"?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the spec essentially leaves this up to the driver; it doesn't specify whether or not already-processed work is committed if the batch fails.

PgJDBC executes the batch in a transaction, so if any part of the batch fails then it will all be aborted.

If you feel this behaviour to be incorrect, the first thing you need to do is write a test case demonstrating that other drivers consistently behave a different way to PgJDBC and submit it to [the PgJDBC issue tracker](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues). We do not have time to research behaviour of other drivers, so *you need to write the test case* and run it some other popular databases (MS SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, MySQL, etc) or arrange to have it run by others. If you show that PgJDBC's behaviour differs from how other drivers handle batches then it'll be worth thinking about adding an option to change the behaviour (and working on making it the default eventually).

Comment: I don't think you can change the driver's behavior - after all Postgres itself does not allow a transaction to be committed if one statement failed. Which is different in e.g. Oracle where you can commit a transaction even if an intermediate DML statement failed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's possible to change the driver's behaviour in this case, if desired. `PreparedStatement` batches (which is what I assume this question is about) are sent as a single `Parse` message on the wire, followed by multiple `Bind/Describe/Execute` messages, one per batch entry. If a transaction is not already open then one is opened with an initial `BEGIN` and finishing `COMMIT`. It is trivial to do this in autocommit by omitting the wrapping transaction delineating statements.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not only that, but the v3 protocol behaviour matches what the spec wants. If there's an error in a statement, Pg will flush the rest of the stream until it hits a `Sync` message from the client. So we don't have to worry about preventing execution of follow-on statements after an error - something the spec permits, but is a *terrible* idea in practice.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So if the OP can show convincing reason why the driver's current behaviour is incorrect I don't see it being especially hard to change, unless there's a wrinkle I've missed somewhere.

Comment: thanks for your replies..
@CraigRinger if possible I will check other driver behaviors..
I was just concern about the JDBC specification. When we use the executeUpdate method of the PS we go by its documentation.
The way I have understood it is, successful inserts should be retained and executing further inserts after the failure is driver dependent.
The link that I have shared above is also saying the same thing, isn't it?

Comment: Guys I forgot to mention that the successful insertions are not rolled back if we use Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS. This thing adds to my confusion.

Comment: @MukeshNegi Hm, that makes it smell more like a bug. Can you produce a JUnit test case, perhaps as a patch adding a few more cases to `org/postgresql/test/jdbc2/BatchExecuteTest.class` in the driver source tree?

Comment: If us use Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS, all statements are executed one by one. This is a lot slower, as always in autocommit mode. The actual sense of executing as a batch is making them all behave like one single statement, which cannot succeed in parts.

Comment: @HolgerJakobs Actually, they *might* be executed one-by-one, depending on whether the driver can figure out the width of their return data types(s). I strongly recommend that you avoid batches in autocommit mode.