# Batch didn't run, JDBC

Tags: java, database, jdbc, prepared-statement

I got a little problem with running my batch process..

First of all, I'm still at learning JDBC etc. so please excuse me, if my mistake is really stupid..

I have to insert some SQL queries into my database. Therefore, I'm building my PreparedStatements like this:

```
String add = "INSERT INTO company_type VALUES (?,?)";
PreparedStatement company = write.getConnection().prepareStatement(add);

ResultSet com = types.getCompanyType();

while(com.next()) {
    System.out.print("1");
    company.setInt(1, com.getInt(1));
    company.setString(2, com.getString(2));
    company.addBatch();

    if(i > size) {
        company.executeBatch();
        i = 0;
    }
    i++;
} 

company.executeBatch();
```

After going through with the debugger, I know something went wrong with the `company.executeBatch();` line.

It just didn't execute and it seems like the program i running into a loop or standing still.

Is there anybody, how can see a mistake?

Thanks

P.s. I did not get any Exception.

```
public Connection getConnection(){

    Connection connection = null;

    try{
        Class.forName( "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" );
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        this.loginmessage.setText("Fehler beim Laden des Oracle JDBC Treibers!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return connection;
    }

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("j******************);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        this.loginmessage.setText("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return connection;
    }

    if (connection != null) {
        loginmessage.setText("Verbindung hergestellt!");
        return connection;
    } else {
        loginmessage.setText("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen!");
        System.out.print("huaha");
    }
    return connection;
}
```

Comment: Do you get any exception? If yes which one? ([Edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Hey, first of all, thanks for answering.. No, i didn't get any exception :S

Comment: Missing `commit()` maybe?

Comment: It could be nice to know the DB and to know what is `write` type and `write.getConnection` (if it is your own implementation or not)

Comment: I'm reading from a PostgreSQL Database and try to write into a Oracle Database
I'll post the methods upside

Comment: You might need to check [Batch update in Postgresql JDBC driver rolls back in autocommit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485287/batch-update-in-postgresql-jdbc-driver-rolls-back-in-autocommit). Check the result of the `executeBatch` method. It might tell you that some rows have failed to be inserted, aborting the transaction for the batch, as PostgreSQL seems to have decide to do so.

Comment: FYI: don't return `connection` (being `null`)  in case of an `Exception`..., this doesn't make sense, throw an exception instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have to commit the transaction like so,

```
write.getConnection().commit();
```

Here are the steps involved in batch processing,

1. First turn off `autocommit`, so that all the Batch statements execute
   in a single transaction and no operation in the batch is committed
   individually. After all this is what we need.
2. Using `addBatch` add as many statements as required to the Batch.
3. Then execute the Batch of statements by invoking the
   `executeBatch()`
4. Finally `commit` or `roll-back` the transaction.

A sample code is given below.

```
public void saveLogEntries(List<LogEntry> entries) {
    try (Connection connObj = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_DB_URL, JDBC_USER, JDBC_PASS);
        PreparedStatement prepareStatement = connObj
            .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO logentry (date, ip, request) values(?, ?,?)")) {
                connObj.setAutoCommit(false);
                for(LogEntry entry : entries) {
                    try {
                        prepareStatement.setString(1, entry.getDate());
                        prepareStatement.setString(2, entry.getIp());
                        prepareStatement.setString(3, entry.getRequest());
                        prepareStatement.addBatch();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        // Handle SQL exception here.
                    }
                };

                prepareStatement.executeBatch();
                connObj.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // Handle SQL exception here.
    }
}
```

However `Class.forName()` is NOT needed anymore. Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220724/class-fornamejdbc-driver-no-longer-needed) for further details. You may change the way you obtain the connection and try it again. The code seems bit clumsy to me.

Comment: I've read about that but before I added some new querrys, everything worked in the way i posted. I'll try it with the commit().. Thanks :)

Comment: I added it behind my executeBatch() lines but still something went wrong.. It seems like it didn't solve the problem :/
Oh you edited your answer, i'll be back in a few minuits :D

Comment: Try following the steps mentioned in my answer and sample code.

Comment: Why you have two `executeBatch` statements? what is the purpose?

Comment: **Assuming OP did set the auto commit to false.** Or is it design to only use a batch in one transaction ? FYI: About the two execute batch, if you have 100k row to insert, you don't want to send one batch, you send multiple small batch

Comment: My prof told us, we have to use :D Guess because we're working with the imdbDatabase and some of the querrys return some big insert statements

Comment: Ok then it is used to limit the batch size. Did you add `.commit()` to both the places where you use `executeBatch()` ?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is you haven't committed so the server-side transaction times out and rolls back.